# How to turn debug mode off? I am trying to stop the code from executing twice Everytime I run it

Tags: javascript, debugging, npm, office-js, webpack-dev-server

I am building a Outlook add-in and randomly it appears some kind of debugger got turned on. When I put some console.logs I get the message twice and it comes from my .js module and a VM version of my js with links different then mine. I need to stop this from occurring. I have a call to an external api and I was calling it twice each time and running up allowable call limits quickly in testing. I need it to only run once.
ENV: Running NPM Dev-server with webpack.

Webpack Dev-server config
'''

```
 devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },      
      https: (options.https !== undefined) ? options.https : await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000
    }
  };
```

'''

Here is my taskpane.js
'''

```
var riskScore = 0;
Office.onReady(info => {
 
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
    document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
    reviewEmailInfo();
    attachmentCheck();
    //var linkRisk = checkBodyforLinks();  
    console.log(riskScore);
    //Need to pass the risk score to the HTML and display
  
  }
});

export async function run() {

}

function reviewEmailInfo(){
  //Return-Path is the reply to area
  console.log("emtering reviewEmailInfo");
  Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(
    function(asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            var headers = asyncResult.value;     
            var ReplyTo = headers.replace(" ","").match(/Return-Path:(.*)/);
            if (ReplyTo.length != null){
              var cleanEmail = ReplyTo[1].substring(2,ReplyTo.length-1);
              if(cleanEmail == Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress){
                document.getElementById("reply-match").innerHTML= "The from and reply email address match";
              }else{
                riskScore += 5;
                document.getElementById("reply-match").innerHTML= "The from and reply email address DO NOT MATCH. The sender is:" + Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress + "  and the reply addres is: " + cleanEmail;
              }
            }
            var ARCAuthResult = headers.replace(" ","").match(/ARC-Authentication-Results:(.*)/);
            var dkimChk = false;
            var spfChk = false;
            if(ARCAuthResult != null){
              if(ARCAuthResult[1].search("spf=pass")){
                spfChk = true;
              }
              if(ARCAuthResult[1].search("dkim=pass")){
                dkimChk = true;
              }
              if(spfChk == true & dkimChk==true){
                document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "Both DKIM and SPF are safe";
              }else if(spfChk == true){
                riskScore += 5;
                document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "DKIM check failed";
              }else if(dkimChk == true){
                riskScore += 5;
                document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "SPF check failed";
              }else{
                riskScore += 10;
                document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "SPF amd DKIM check failed";
              }
            }else{
              var AuthResult = headers.replace(" ","").match(/Authentication-Results:(.*)/);
              if(AuthResult.length != null){
                if(AuthResult[1].search("spf=pass")){
                  spfChk = true;
                }
                if(AuthResult[1].search("dkim=pass")){
                  dkimChk = true;
                }
                if(spfChk == true & dkimChk==true){
                  document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "Both DKIM and SPF are safe";
                }else if(spfChk == true){
                  riskScore += 5;
                  document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "DKIM check failed";
                }else if(dkimChk == true){
                  riskScore += 5;
                  document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "SPF check failed";
                }else{
                  riskScore += 10;
                  document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "SPF amd DKIM check failed";
                }
              }
            }     
            //Check for domain match between sender and reciever
            var domainIndex = Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress.indexOf("@");
            var senderDomain = Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress.slice((domainIndex+1), Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress.length);
            var receiverAddress = headers.replace(" ","").match(/To:(.*)/);
            if (receiverAddress.length != null){
              domainIndex = receiverAddress[1].indexOf("@");
              var recieverDomain = receiverAddress.slice((domainIndex+1),receiverAddress.length-1);

              if(senderDomain == recieverDomain){
                document.getElementById("domainMatch").innerHTML = "This email comes from with your domain";
             }else {
                riskScore += 1;
                document.getElementById("domainMatch").innerHTML = "This is an external email address";
              }
              }
            return;         
        } else {
            if (asyncResult.error.code == 9020) {
                // GenericResponseError returned when there is no context.
                // Treat as no context.
            } else {
                console.log("error");
              }
          }
      }
  );
  return;
}

function attachmentCheck() {
  var currentmail = Office.context.mailbox.item;
  var htmlString = "There appears to be no unsafe attachments";
  var attachmentArray = currentmail.attachments;
  for(var i =0; i < attachmentArray.length; i++){
    if(attachmentArray[i].contentType.includes(".exe")){
      //add a boolean. Check boolean and length if greater then 1 then no risky attachments else empty
      riskScore += 5;
    }
    if(attachmentArray[i].contentType.includes(".app")){
      riskScore += 5;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("attachment-count").innerHTML="<b> There are a total of </b></br>" + attachmentArray.length + "<b> attachments </b>";
  document.getElementById("attachment-msg").innerHTML = htmlString;
  return;
}
```

'''

Here is the html
'''

```
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT License. -->
<!-- This file shows how to design a first-run page that provides a welcome screen to the user about the features of the add-in. -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Contoso Task Pane Add-in</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>

    <!-- For more information on Office UI Fabric, visit https://developer.microsoft.com/fabric. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css"/>

    <!-- Template styles -->
    <link href="taskpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="taskpane.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body class="ms-font-m ms-welcome ms-Fabric">
    <header class="ms-welcome__header ms-bgColor-neutralLighter">
        <img width="90" height="90" src="../../assets/logo-filled.png" alt="Contoso" title="Contoso" />
        <h1 class="ms-font-su">Welcome to your Email Security Assistant</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="sideload-msg" class="ms-welcome__main">
        <h2 class="ms-font-xl">Please sideload your add-in to see app body.</h2>
    </section>
    <main id="app-body" class="ms-welcome__main" style="display: none;">
        <div>
            <h2>Secuirty Checks</h2>
                <h3>Attachments</h3>
                    <p><label id="attachment-count"></label></p>            
                    <p><label id="attachment-msg"></label></p>
                <h3>Embedded Links</h3>
                    <p id="linkCheck"></p>
                <h3>Header Checks</h3>
                <p><label id="reply-match"></label></p>
                <p><label id="dkimspfchk"></label></p>
                <p><label id="domainMatch"></label></p>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

'''

This is what I am seeing in the console on Chrome

```
emtering reviewEmailInfo VM7 taskpane.js:9823 ***- This is the debugger run I want to remove***
0 taskpane.js:34 
emtering reviewEmailInfo taskpane.js:22 
0
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>6d1f7324-ed55-4c8b-9e8a-f9b66119a631</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="EmailAssistant"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

webpack.config.js

```
const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const fs = require("fs");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: "@babel/polyfill",
      taskpane: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.js",
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.js"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader", 
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
          use: "file-loader"
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane"]
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          to: "taskpane.css",
          from: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.css"
        }
      ]),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "commands"]
      })
    ],
    devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },      
      https: (options.https !== undefined) ? options.https : await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000
    }
  };

  return config;
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: Sorry about that I just added it into the text. I need this to stop. It is causing issues when I try to call an api. I call it twice and it hinders my testing due to daily limits on call for the free version of the api.

Comment: What is the source location in your add-in manifest? Do you only have a taskpane defined? Are you only seeing the issue in OWA or have you tried Outlook desktop on Windows or Mac?

Comment: I have added the wepack config and the manifest. I have not made changes to the webpack and only minor the the manifest. I am just trying to stop the bebugger calls because it causes the code to execute twice and its causing issues on other code I want to call

Comment: What platform you are hitting this on? (OWA, windows, mac?)

Comment: Windows using Chrome

Comment: @MichaelMcDermott could you give us a link to your full add-in code or its manifest (with add-in hosted publicly instead of localhost) so we can install, run it and reproduce this from our side? This looks like a very specific case and we will not be able to investigate it unless we can run your add-in